# ¿Por qué usar join sólo me trae la primera fila de la información?

Tags: sql, join

Estoy creando un query que me va a traer una serie de filas donde solo es diferente el dato `release_no`, pero sólo me trae la primera línea.

Este es mi código:

```html
SELECT D.Part_No,D.Name,E.Customer_Part_No,A.Release_No,A.Quantity,G.Shipper_No,C.PO_No,E.Customer_Part_Description,A.Ship_Date,H.Customer_Address_Code
FROM Sales_v_Release_e A
LEFT JOIN Sales_v_PO_Line_e B ON A.PO_Line_Key = B.PO_Line_Key
LEFT JOIN Sales_v_PO C ON B.PO_Key = C.PO_Key
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Part_e D ON B.Part_Key = D.Part_Key
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Customer_Part E ON B.Part_Key = E.Part_Key
LEFT JOIN Sales_v_Shipper_Line_e F ON A.Release_Key = F.Release_Key
LEFT JOIN Sales_v_Shipper_e G ON F.Shipper_Key = G.Shipper_Key
LEFT JOIN Common_v_customer_address_e H ON G.Customer_Address_No = H.Customer_Address_No
WHERE Release_Status_Key = 75 AND Customer_Address_Code = @PLANTA
```

Comment: Si trae una sola fila es porque hay una sola fila uniendo las tablas así. Revisa la consulta, puedes ir quitando los `JOIN` uno a uno hasta que te traiga lo que esperas, entonces sabrás que hay un problema en ese `JOIN`.

Comment: Y nosotros como sabriamos que tiene que traer mas de una fila? Para eso, nevesitariamos ver los datos de cada tabla que vos pensas que se van a mezclar y la salida que vos essperas segun esos datos. Asi como esta, la pregunta es demasiado amplia

Answer (score -2):

Revisa la condición que pusiste en el where. No especificaste a que tabla corresponde la columna Release_Status_Key ni Customer_Address_Code (En mi opinion pienso que es importante especificarlo si estás haciendo joins entre varias tablas) Además en el query que compartes no se observa que valor le has asignado a la variable @PLANTA. 
WHERE Release_Status_Key = 75 AND Customer_Address_Code = @PLANTA

Revisa esos datos y tendrás más visión de los resultados que estas obteniendo con tu query

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer] ya que esta publicación fue reportada como de "baja calidad", saludos.